# Cloufflare terraform on a per site bases

Tags: terraform, cloudflare

we are looking at using Terraform to manage our Cloudflare implementation. However, there are a few sites(zones) that we what to exclude and still manage via the UI.

This will of cause create a conflict between the UI and Terraform settings where Terraform would like to override the UI settings every time it gets applied.

Is there a way to tell Terraform to effectively ignore those zones and to only apply changes for zones in its remit?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to put the sites you want to manage via the UI into Terraform at all? Terraform won't magically start managing all your existing Cloudflare resources and you will need to import them into state and write Terraform code for each of the resources before it will do so. There's also the option of using `ignore_changes` if you want to have Terraform manage most of a resource but have some key parts managed outside of Terraform's lifecycle.

Comment: We are still getting to grips with Cloudflare. In terms of learning the UI is the easiest.  I manage to reverse engineer the first few zones into a Terraform format. Some zones settings will be "stable" and wouldn't change that often, other less so and why the UI is preferred for operational reasons. It is also to serve as a backup solution.  
I will have a look at `ignore_changes` option. Thank you @ydaetskcoR